# Loop through over JSON

Tags: javascript, json

How do I loop over through json in javascript this kind of structure. Thank you in advance.

```
{
  "logged_in": true,
  "town": "Dublin",
  "state": "Ohio",
  "country": "USA",
  "urls": [{
    "0": {
      "url": "wwww.nba.com"
    },
    "1": {
      "url": "www.searchpage.com"
    }
  }],
  "keywords": [{
    "0": {
      "keyword": "install"
    },
    "1": {
      "keyword": "how%20to%20install"
    }
  }]
}​
```

Comment: Do you want to loop over the nested objects as well?

Comment: What do you want to loop over?

Comment: Please google how iterate JSON

Comment: What have you tried? You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**, if you want us to give it a go at least specify an expected output.

Comment: @PeterMader, Yes i want to loop on the nested objects as well. Thank you

Comment: @JohnWick, The problem is that you want to loop for what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want iterate `urls` and `keywords` properties with this kind of structure then

```
// iterate over urls
for (let index in obj.urls[0]) {
    let value = obj.urls[0][index];
    console.log(value);
}

// iterate over keywords
for (let index in obj.keywords[0]) {
    let value = obj.keywords[0][index];
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have an object and objects have properties, so we need to iterate those properties...

```js
var jsonResult = `{
  "logged_in": true,
  "town": "Dublin",
  "state": "Ohio",
  "country": "USA",
  "urls": [{
    "0": {
      "url": "wwww.nba.com"
    },
    "1": {
      "url": "www.searchpage.com"
    }
  }],
  "keywords": [{
    "0": {
      "keyword": "install"
    },
    "1": {
      "keyword": "how%20to%20install"
    }
  }]
}`;

var jObj = JSON.parse(jsonResult);

(function listProps(obj){
  for(var prop in obj){
    if(typeof obj[prop] === "object"){
      listProps(obj[prop]);
    } else {
      console.log(prop + ":" + obj[prop]);
    }
  }
})(jObj);
```

Comment: I want to iterate with that kind of structure without wrapping it in a var jsonresult, Is it possible?

Comment: @JohnWick Well, your JSON is coming in from somewhere and being captured in a variable. You have to have something that references it since it's not an object literal.